# Copy Word file table to Excel file (merged cells and multiple-line cells)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste, word-table

In another post I finally got to choose a table from a Word file and get it to an Excel file. I have the following code in Word VBA:

```
    Dim wrdTbl As Table
    Dim RowCount As Long, ColCount As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    'Excel Objects
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object

    'Set your table
    Set wrdTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(InputBox("Table # to copy? There are " & ActiveDocument.Tables.Count & " tables to choose from."))

    'If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "There are no tables in word document"
        'Exit Sub

    'Get the word table Row and Column counts
    ColCount = wrdTbl.Columns.Count
    RowCount = wrdTbl.Rows.Count

    'Create a new Excel Application
    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'Hide Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = False

    'Open the relevant Excel file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\ExcelEx.xlsx")
    'Work with Sheet1. Change as applicable
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets(1)

    'Loop through each row of the table
    For i = 1 To RowCount
        'Loop through each cell of the row
        For j = 1 To ColCount
        'This gives you the cell contents
            wrdTbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Copy

            With oXLws
                .Range("A1").Activate
                .Cells(i, j).Select
                .PasteSpecial (wdPasteText)
                .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Style = "Normal"
            End With

        Next
    Next

    'Close and save Excel file
    oXLwb.Close savechanges:=True

    'Cleanup (VERY IMPORTANT)
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    oXLApp.Quit
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

My problem is that if I have a table with merged cells it throws the error: "5941" requested member of the collection does not exist on the line:

`wrdTbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Copy`

How can I get the code to copy merged cells too?

Another problem it is when I have a cell with multiple lines because in the Excel file it copies these cell lines in different cells in Excel. How can I solve this too?
Thank you so much for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the cells individually, rather than by rows and columns. For example:

```
Dim wrdTbl As Table, c As Long
'Excel Objects
Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object

'Set your table
With ActiveDocument
    If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "There are no tables in word document"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wrdTbl = .Tables(InputBox("Table # to copy? There are " & .Tables.Count & " tables to choose from."))
    End If
End With

'Create a new Excel Application
Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With oXLApp
'Hide Excel
    .Visible = False

    'Open the relevant Excel file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\ExcelEx.xlsx")
End With

'Loop through each row of the table
With wrdTbl.Range
    For c = 1 To .Cells.Count
        With .Cells(c)            
          'Work with Sheet1. Change as applicable
          oXLwb.Sheets(1).Cells(.RowIndex, .ColumnIndex).Value = Split(.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
        End With
    Next
End With

'Close and save Excel file
oXLwb.Close True

'Cleanup (VERY IMPORTANT)
oXLApp.Quit
Set oXLwb = Nothing: Set oXLApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"
```

If you want to replicate the Word table in Excel, replace:

```
'Loop through each row of the table
With wrdTbl.Range
    For c = 1 To .Cells.Count
        With .Cells(c)
          'Work with Sheet1. Change as applicable
          oXLwb.Sheets(1).Cells(.RowIndex, .ColumnIndex).Value = Split(.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
        End With
    Next
End With
```

with:

```
wrdTbl.Range.Copy
With oXLwb.Sheets(1)
.Paste .Range("A1")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, I’ll check if it works tomorrow morning as I don’t have my computer now, I’ll tell you here. Thank you :)

Comment: Furthermore @macropod , how can I use the code to give a table format in excel from the table in word? I mean, to give it a format in excel using the code in word.

Comment: I checked your answer and it does not run as it says “Method or data member not found” in ```.Range``` in ```oXLwb.Sheets(1).Cells(.RowIndex, .ColumnIndex).Value = Split(.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)``` how can I solve this?

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly!! Just one last question if you can help me, is there any way to change the format in excel of that table with this macro? I mean I’d like to change it to be a “Table” in excel, because I’ll later use that table in another app and I need it to be formatted as Table like when in excel you insert a table.

Comment: I suggest you read, for example, https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables. If you can't work out what to do from there, start a new thread.